# Slim Twig View return $view as null when used in render function

Tags: php, twig, slim

Hello I am having an issue while rendering the page, i hope someone can help me with it.
I have tried changing the directory structure as well creating a new project with similar code , but nothing works for me .

[image: Error Message]

[image: directory structure]

routes.php

```
<?php

$app->get('/home' , function() {
return $this->view->render($response,'home.twig');
});
```

app.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings'=> [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ]
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', [
        'cache' => __DIR__.'../cache',
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container['router'],
        $container['request']->getUri()

    ));

    return $view;
};

require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
```

index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->run();
```

Comment: It looks like you have to set `$response` in routes.php to an object that implements the ResponseInterface interface. I'm not very familiar with Slim but it looks like you have forgotten to set the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Slim templates section](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html).

The closure needs extra parameters in routes.php:

```
// Render Twig template in route
$app->get('/home', function ($request, $response) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
});
```